# Android, получение конкретных данных из сложного GSON ответа через Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, gson

Имею очень сложный GSON ответ от сервера, в котором где - то на седьмом уровне вложенности находятся интересующие меня данные, ключ которых мне заранее известен.

Структура сложная - в верхушке это массив, в каждом из которых ещё несколько массивов, в каждом из которых еще по паре массивов, и в каждом из них лист с заранее неизвестным количеством данных, в одном из них массив, в котором...(e.t.c);

В разработке я недавно, и создать модель для этих данных для меня выглядит чем - то дико нереальным вообще, мне этот запрос даже осознать сложно. Может быть есть какие - нибудь варианты(библиотеки/фреймворки/подходы), которые облегчат задачу?

Comment: приведите пример json'а

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ - Java; Плагин в IDE `JsonToKotlinClass` - Kotlin